# Coding in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working on jupyter notebooks first time and created code like this :

[image: Jupyter]

Although it ran fine and produced the output. I am not sure if this is the ideal way to use jupyter notebooks. One issue I see with this is I pasted everything in one block.

I am not sure what are the pros n cons of putting code in different blocks.
Any suggestions how this could be improved ?

Comment: why on earth do you use a lot of `<br>` to break down the sentences? Word wrapping must be done by the browser because the width of the page isn't fixed, and if you do that manually it results in terrible unreadable texts in other computers (or even your own when resizing the page)

Answer (score 2):

Jupiter notebooks, google colab notebooks, etc are suposed to be used to run code by sections (like MatLab live scripts as well) the main difference between this and a regular ".py" script is that the memory space where your variables are allocated will not be emptied when you run your code.

So, the main advantage of this notebooks is that you can divide your code in sections and debug just one section at time, another way to debug is using the debug mode in, for instace Visual Studio Code.

In the other hand you can write a very nice documentation of your code, including outputs, images, etc.

Check [this](https://realpython.com/lessons/why-use-jupyter-notebooks/) video.